# Free particle in one dimension, gaussian distribution question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, probability, hamiltonian

Okay, so the question im struggling with is:

Given a free particle in one dimension(with $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$) in a state $p$ at $x=0$ with uncertainty $\sigma$(Gaussian Distribution) determine the time-independent state $\rho(p,q,t)$. Assume $ne^{-\frac{x^2+p^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$ at $t=0$, where $n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The key to doing this problem is to realize that for every $p$ and $x$ the future trajectory is fully determined by Hamilton's equations of motion,
\begin{align}
    \dot{x} & = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} \\
    \dot{p} & = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}.
\end{align}
Because the phase space position fixes the phase space velocity, $\vec{v} \equiv (\dot{x}, \dot{p})$, you can find the current density by $\vec{J} \equiv \vec{v} \rho$. You also know that the particle number is conserved, so the density and current have to obey the [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation)
$$\dot{\rho} = - \frac{\partial J_x}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial J_p}{\partial p}.$$

Once you've plugged everything in, the continuity equation becomes a first order partial differential equation that you can solve using the boundary condition at $t=0$ given in the question.

There are several ways to solve that partial differential equation, and one way is to change to Fourier space in the $x$ direction. If we let
$$\tilde{\rho}(k,p,t) \equiv \int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(x,p,t) \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-ikx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \operatorname{d} x$$
Then the partial differential equaiton for $\rho(x,p,t)$ becomes an ordinary differential equation for $\tilde{\rho}(k,p,t)$ that should be easily recognizable. In terms of relevant variables, it has the form
$$\dot{\tilde{\rho}} = -\frac{ikp}{m} \tilde{\rho}.$$

Once the correct form for $\tilde{\rho(k,p,t)}$ has been found, it is a straightforward [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) of the type used all of the time in quantum mechanics to get back to $\rho(x,p,t)$.